# getting error org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8, eclipse-mars

I'm running a program for Login using selenium WebDriver and getting an error. What could be the reason?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: GIF89a
Command duration or timeout: 156 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'VRDT32', ip: '172.18.1.152', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at LoginPage.main(LoginPage.java:11)
```

**Edit:** OP says this code was working before:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LoginPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://180.211.114.147:97/Account/Login");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys("Chetna123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("Chetna123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: probably u r getting this error at when you use sendkeys .also please show us your code

Comment: can you please share the code you are using. It will help us to help you better

Comment: given code, it was working earlier:
`import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LoginPage {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  driver.get("http://180.211.114.147:97/Account/Login");
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UserName']")).sendKeys("Chetna123");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys("Chetna123");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();
 }
}`

Comment: This looks like a WebDriver / Firefox bug (at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/JsonHttpCommandCodec.java#L221). What Selenium and Firefox versions are you running? Also, have you tried in any other browser?

Comment: FF#45.0.1, SW#2.53.0 (Mars)

Comment: FF#45.0.1, SW#2.53.0 (Mars), JDK 8(66 update)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a public URL for recreating this?

Comment: Its working on G chrome#49. Also the same code working on other machine. Seems setup issue, I did the resetup again, but still not working.

Comment: I can't help without the real URL or a way of recreating this. Even if you raised a bug @ SeleniumHQ you'd still need to do that.